# Sql Server 2012 left join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, left-join

I am using sql server 2012. I have a table with named ProcessHistory. I have six different process types and I need to get total process count for each process types. When I execute my query I get following result:

```
ProcessType Count
0            1
1            3
```

But I need to get result like this:

```
ProcessType Count
    0            1
    1            3
    2            0
    4            0
    5            0
    6            0
```

So I need to value even if total count equals to zero. To achieve this I try this query:

```
SELECT T.processtype, 
       count(*) AS Count 
FROM   (SELECT 0          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process1' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process2' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process3' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process4' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process5' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process6' AS Type) AS T 
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[processhistory] I 
              ON T.processtype = I.processtype 
WHERE  optime > DateADD(mi, -60, GETDATE()) 
GROUP  BY T.processtype
```

This query didn't work as I expected. Interestingly this query with inner join giving me same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is asserting a condition that must be true for all rows produced by the `FROM` clause. And the specific condition you've given will not be true for the rows that remain when the `LEFT JOIN` doesn't find a match. Try:

```
SELECT T.processtype, 
       count(I.nonnullablecolumn) AS Count 
FROM   (SELECT 0          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process1' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process2' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process3' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process4' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process5' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process6' AS Type) AS T 
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[processhistory] I 
              ON T.processtype = I.processtype 
WHERE  optime > DateADD(minute, -60, GETDATE()) OR optime IS NULL
GROUP  BY T.processtype
```

(Assuming that `optime` isn't nullable in `processhistory`). Or:

```
SELECT T.processtype, 
       count(I.nonnullablecolumn) AS Count 
FROM   (SELECT 0          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process1' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process2' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process3' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process4' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process5' AS Type 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6          AS ProcessType, 
               'Process6' AS Type) AS T 
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[processhistory] I 
              ON T.processtype = I.processtype AND
                 I.optime > DateADD(minute, -60, GETDATE())
GROUP  BY T.processtype
```

---

I've also adjusted the `COUNT()` expressions because otherwise the rows where the `LEFT JOIN` didn't find a match would be a `1` rather than a `0`.